# How can I stop Resharper from requiring me to press tab 2-3 times instead of just 2 to use "prop"?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, resharper

I abhor Resharper's version of code snippets ("templates") and even though I've forcibly deleted all of the templates from the Template Editor and disabled structural navigation (as suggested by a Google search), Resharper has changed the behavior that I now need to press tab an inconsistent number of times (2 slowly or 3 quickly) after typing `prop` instead of the usual 2 times (always).  How do I turn this off?

Things to note:

- `IntelliSense` is set to Visual Studio only
- All `Completion Behavior` options are turned off
- All `Completion Filter` options are turned off
- All `Completion Appearance` options are turned off
- All `Live Templates` and `Surround Templates` have been deleted
- `Keyboard Shortcuts` are set to Visual Studio
- `Hide Overridden Visual Studio Menu Items` is off
- `Structural Navigation` is off

Comment: This might be a long shot, but how is your machine doing overall, performance wise? Resharpser + VS 2017 can be pretty resource consuming, and if it's inconsistent and 'sometimes works', then perhaps you have a different problem.

Comment: @Bartosz I have a decent machine that was recently built (16 GB RAM, i5-7300).  After installing Resharper, however, the IDE has become increasingly unstable and slow with weird quirks that are trying to undo years of muscle memory.